# Hot reload not working with Bigcommerce/Stencil on docker

Tags: docker, bigcommerce, browser-sync

I would like to use Docker because [bigcommerce/stencil-cli](https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli) only supports node version 10x or 12x. I can't configure docker correctly for the reload (browsersync) to work.

When I edit any SASS or HTML theme files my changes are not showing at localhost:3000.

I don't really understand why, the configuration seems ok to me.

Here is the Dockerfile config

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /theme
RUN npm -g config set user root
RUN npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli

EXPOSE 3000 3001 3002
```

I am using the default [Cornerstone Theme](https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone)

To build my docker image.

```
docker build -t docker-stencil .
```

To run the docker container

```
docker run -it -v /$(pwd):/theme -p3000:3000 -p3001:3001 -p3002:3002 docker-stencil stencil start
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized stencil on the container with ‘stencil init’? From the commands you posted, it looks like this step may have been skipped. The CLI could be looking at your machine and not the docker vm instance if it was initialized on their machine first, if that’s the case.

Let me know!
Also, this is a great resource as well to keep around: [Dockerizing BC Stencil](https://medium.com/bigcommerce-developer-blog/dockerizing-bigcommerces-stencil-cli-f508ddc0c3c0)!

Comment: Yes, I did initialize stencil on the container with "stencil init". It still does not work. I also followed every step in the documentation you mentioned. Still no success!

Comment: Have you seen any errors when you run these stencil commands? Or any errors in general in this process? @Amit